# Why is my plot looking different than the author's plot?

Tags: plotting

I am plotting the equation

```
4 Sqrt[3] x^7 + x^6 (4 - 3 y^2) + 2 Sqrt[3] x^5 (-70 + 9 y^2) + 
  4 Sqrt[3] x^3 (-513 - 19 y^2 + 6 y^4) + 
  2 Sqrt[3] x (-170 - 1263 y^2 + 68 y^4 + 5 y^6) == 
 9 x^4 (156 - 13 y^2 + y^4) + (3 + y^2) (-388 + 963 y^2 - 82 y^4 + 
     3 y^6) + x^2 (3860 + 2013 y^2 - 186 y^4 + 9 y^6)
```

using `ContourPlot`. This is the plot I got

[image]

However in a published paper, the author got

[image]

Where do the two lines at the right come from in my plot.

Comment: With `ContourPlot` you can wite: `ContourPlot[f==g,{x,xmin,xmax},{y,ymin,ymax}]` (see: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html )  so maybe the author used a different value for `g`.

Comment: Are you saying that you do not trust the result you got?  If yes, have you tried plotting this in any other way to verify it?  Make a `Plot3D`.  Or plot a section at `x==9`.  There are many ways.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I did make `Plot3D` but I am not sure whether the graph matches mine or the author's.

Comment: If you plot the section I suggested, it will be clear that the contour plot you get is correct.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Is there a way to illuminate the two lines from the plot?

Comment: I don't think this is a well-posed question. The OP asks about why some author, in some paper, using some method achieved his/her result. How could we know what the author had in mind?

Comment: Its a fair question to say you have some reason to suspect the plot might be wrong, and ask how to check/verify.  `ContourPlot` does sometimes produce spurious invalid solutions especially where there is a sign change due to a singularity. (not the case here of course).  Asking what the other guy did wrong is ill posed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
eqn = 4 Sqrt[3] x^7 + x^6 (4 - 3 y^2) + 2 Sqrt[3] x^5 (-70 + 9 y^2) + 
    4 Sqrt[3] x^3 (-513 - 19 y^2 + 6 y^4) + 
    2 Sqrt[3] x (-170 - 1263 y^2 + 68 y^4 + 5 y^6) == 
   9 x^4 (156 - 13 y^2 + y^4) + (3 + y^2) (-388 + 963 y^2 - 82 y^4 + 3 y^6) + 
    x^2 (3860 + 2013 y^2 - 186 y^4 + 9 y^6);
```

Solving for `y`

```
solns = Solve[eqn, y, Reals] // Normal;

Length[solns]

(*  6  *)
```

The solution has six segments (three mirrored pairs)

```
Plot[Evaluate[y /. solns], {x, -9, 9},
 PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-9, 9}},
 Frame -> True,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

You wish to delete the last two solutions.

**EDIT:** Added [`Filling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html)

```
Plot[Evaluate[y /. solns[[1 ;; 4]]], {x, -9, 9},
 PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-9, 9}},
 PlotStyle -> Blue,
 Frame -> True,
 AspectRatio -> 1, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, FontWeight -> Bold},
 Filling -> 1 -> {2}]
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to fill in the closed curved in the middle :P

Comment: @anderstood - added Filling

Comment: a bit aside i suppose but that filled region is not a solution, so why should it be filled?

Comment: @george2079 - only because the OP requested reproducing a given plot

Answer (score 3):

From looking at the two intersecting surfaces in 3D, I conclude that the lines you want to eliminate from your contour plot belong there.

```
Plot3D[
  {4 Sqrt[3] x^7 + x^6 (4 - 3 y^2) + 
     2 Sqrt[3] x^5 (-70 + 9 y^2) + 
     4 Sqrt[3] x^3 (-513 - 19 y^2 + 6 y^4) + 
     2 Sqrt[3] x (-170 - 1263 y^2 + 68 y^4 + 5 y^6), 
   9 x^4 (156 - 13 y^2 + y^4) + 
     (3 + y^2) (-388 + 963 y^2 - 82 y^4 + 3 y^6) + 
     x^2 (3860 + 2013 y^2 - 186 y^4 + 9 y^6)},
  {x, -5, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
  Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> None,
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  ClippingStyle -> None,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  ImageSize -> 450]
```

[image: plot3D]

Presuming you agree to keep the lines, you can improve the look of your contour plot by giving a few options:

```
ContourPlot[
  4 Sqrt[3] x^7 + x^6 (4 - 3 y^2) + 2 Sqrt[3] x^5 (-70 + 9 y^2) + 
    4 Sqrt[3] x^3 (-513 - 19 y^2 + 6 y^4) + 
    2 Sqrt[3] x (-170 - 1263 y^2 + 68 y^4 + 5 y^6) == 
  9 x^4 (156 - 13 y^2 + y^4) + 
    (3 + y^2) (-388 + 963 y^2 - 82 y^4 + 3 y^6) + 
    x^2 (3860 + 2013 y^2 - 186 y^4 + 9 y^6),
 {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 Axes -> True,
 AxesStyle -> Dotted]
```

[image: plot]

The extra plot points are needed to properly show the two cusps at `x = 5.53423, y = ±5`.